# Ceating and storing a message template in Javamail API

Tags: java, api, email

I ask for advice.

I have a specific task: check the correspondence between the received mail message and the existing template.

I divided the task into steps:

- Create a session (completed)
- Receive an object store (completed)
- Receive a message (completed)
- Save the title of the message(completed)
- Save the contents of the message (completed)

Check for compliance with the header and contents of the message with the message header template and the contents of the message (not completed)

Question: how to create a message template using the JavaMail API?

P.S. Preferably look example code

Thanks!

```
Store store = null;
Message result = null;
properties = new Properties().setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", mailImapSslEnable);
session = Session.getInstance(properties);
try {
 store = session.getStore("imap");
 try {
  store.connect(this.HOST_EMAIL, this.USER_NAME_EMAIL, this.PASSWORD_EMAIL);
  Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

  Message[] foundMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
  for (Message m: foundMessages) {
   if (m.getSubject().equals("Account registration")) {
    result = m;
   }
  }
  store.close();
 } catch (MessagingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who responded.

I solved the last item of my task.

Comment: Decision.
I do make preparing a mailbox infrastructure:
I created two folders in the test box.

Comment: Folder 1 - Contains the copied message. This message will be the benchmark for verification. In this message will replace the denami part of the content. This allows you to set up a benchmark message to check for a new incoming message.

Comment: Folder 2 - Letters for verification will be sent to this folder. I configured filters for this folder.

Comment: Software implementation:
1. Connect to the mail server.
2. Received a reference message from Folder 1.

Comment: 3. Transformed the benchmark message with the .getContent (). ToString () to the string
4. In the resulting string, I made the conversion to the expected result using toString (). Replace
5. Modified benchmark message do converted to Document using Jsoup.parse

Comment: 6. Got a message from Folder 2
7. Convert message to Document using Jsoup.parse
8. Document work with DOM-models.